# How to remove sequence pattern from regex selection?

Tags: regex

In the expression below I need to parse some javascript to retrieve JSON `series: []` **except** the `somethingToRemove: {...}` part because it contains stuff causing the JSON parser to crash.

```
javascript code xyz ... series: [{data1:[...], data2:[...], somethingToRemove: {...}  }]
```

This regex `(?:series:)\s(\[.*])` returns `series: []` including the unwanted part.

Is there a way to remove `somethingToRemove: {...}` from the selection **or** to select everything up to the `somethingToRemove:` token ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> to select everything up to the somethingToRemove: token

In this case, you could use positive lookahead assertion.

```
(?:series:)\s(\[.*?)(?=somethingToRemove:)
```

OR

```
(?:series:)\s(\[.*?)(?=,\s*somethingToRemove:)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nS8gE8/1)